# li not aligning in center to ul

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I am struggling to align the li HELLO exactly in the center of the ul But it's getting shifted to the left side. Here, I am not looking for a solution (as I am trying to practice and understand the functionality through this code). But I am most importantly looking for a reason and explanation as to why is this happening.

Even though I have set the left/right margin of the li to auto. Then why is it not coming in the center of the ul ? For visual aid, I have created border for li so that you can easily spot it's exact position. I know that by decreasing/altering the width of the ul , this problem can be corrected. But is there no other way so that the text is aligned in the center automatically (without manually adjusting width,padding etc)? Also if I increase the length of the text or change its font size I want the text to be aligned in the center.

```css
html body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 200px;
}

ul {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 height: 100px;
 width: 150px;
}

li {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 border: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The float on the li takes it out of the flow on the document and just push the element to the left side ... also your ul has a default padding you need to change that to see it absolute centered

Comment: Now you completely made all answers wrong by changing the question like that. Please undo the edit and add it as a new question.

Comment: unable to add new questions dies to many negative votes. thats why modified exsisting question. it says " You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. "

Comment: Doesn't make the edit you did okay, so undo that right a way please, and follow the recommended actions to unlock the block of adding new questions.

Comment: ok sure. but would be helpful if you can please give some positive vote, as i wont be able to post new questions till i recieve positive votes

Comment: Now I rolled back the edit. I recommend you chose and accept an answer that solved the original question, if any. Regarding positive votes, this question have already been upvoted so you have positive votes, either way, you are not allowed to make such an edit that invalidates the already given answers like that. If there is some issues with your account, please contact SO support and find out what it is and how to fix.

Answer (score 3):

It is slightly to the right because the `ul` has a `padding-left` by default; setting `padding-left: 0;` to the `ul` will make it go completely left. Then the `li` isn't centered because you're floating it to the left with `float: left;` this will make it ignore the `margin: auto;` you have set. If you remove the `float` the `li` will be at the center.

I guess you used the `float` because there will be more `li's` in the list and you want them all on one line and centered in the `ul`. In these cases what I usually do is:

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example1</li>  
  <li>Example2</li>
  <li>Example3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. But the ul is not aligned to the center of the page. Its on the left, how can we correct it?

Comment: You mean in your example or mine? Why would you want to align the ul when the li's are aligned?

Comment: It just takes the whole space, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two issues here:

By default `ul` elements render with padding to the left. This is what's given you that spacing and perhaps creating confusion around that element being pushed right.

Additionally, you're adding the `float` property to your `<li>` element. Remove that and you should see your `<li>` centered.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

li {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Now what if I want to add another li next to the Hello one? And I also want both of them to be equally placed? Can this be possible without using float left?